# Confused on the behaviour of the RouteLink helper method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I don't understand why link number 2 below doesn't work :

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "GreetingDefault",
   url: "Greeting/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Greeting", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
)
;
```

The links :

```
1  @Html.ActionLink("ActionLink", "Index", "Greeting", new {area = "" }, null)

2  @Html.RouteLink("RouteLink", "GreetingDefault")

3  @Html.RouteLink("Greet-RouteLink-DisplayGreeting", "GreetingDefault", 
                     new { action = "DisplayGreeting", parameter="abc" })
```

After clicking on the 3rd link, this is the HTML :

```
<a href="/Greeting">ActionLink</a>

<a href="/Greeting/DisplayGreeting">RouteLink</a>

<a href="/Greeting/DisplayGreeting?parameter=abc">Greet-RouteLink-DisplayGreeting</a>
```

then when I click on link 2, it stays at link 3 page, . . instead of going
to "Index" as specified in the named route. I have to do this to make it work :

```
2    @Html.RouteLink("RouteLink", "GreetingDefault",
                     new { action = "Index"} )
```

What am I not seeing here? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `RouteLink` picks up *current* action and uses it in the resulting URL. In your case you are on the page 3, which means your current URL is `/Greeting/DisplayGreeting?parameter=abc`, and so current action is `DisplayGreeting`. That is the one `RouteLink` uses. If you were on the page, say `/Greeting/AnyOtherAction`, `RouteLink` would use `AnyOtherAction` for an action.

Bottom line - `RouteLink` does not use default action defined for a route when current action canbe used. So basically what you have done with explicit override of the action is a right way to go.

Comment: Thanks. This route thing just keeps getting crazier and crazier. I'm going to specify an action every time I use RouteLink just to play it safe.